# I want to open a specific google link and back to the previous page and do the same with others links

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

I was trying to search on google using selenium and when i get the results then open the first link and go back to the previous page and open the second link ...etc and i wanted to do  the same with other links but i don't know where is the probleme

ANY HELP , PLEASE .

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import time


driver = webdriver.Edge()

url = "https://www.google.com/"

driver.get(url)

search_field = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input')

search_field.send_keys("Anime")

search_field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

all_links = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "yuRUbf")

a = 0

for link in all_links :

        link[a].click()

        a += 1

        time.sleep(10)

        driver.back()
```

Comment: Grab and store the hrefs instead.  Then you can loop through them and go to those URLs.

Answer (score 0):

By clicking on a link, browser focus jumps to the new opened tab while selenium driver doesn't do this automatically. So you need to switch a driver to that opened tab. After that you can close that tab and switch driver back to the first tab.

```
browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
    browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[1]);
    // do what you want on the new tab here
    browser.driver.close();
    browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
});
```